# Django view "list index out of range", loop terminating in odd place

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to loop over 3 formsets of models that are related, but it keeps terminating with a "list index out of range" error. However, it does it in a very strange place.
For example, in the following code segment, if num1 is 2, num2 is 4, and num3 is 3, it will loop over the outer for loop correctly once, and then on the second iteration of the outer loop it will only iterate over the first inner for loop twice, and then terminate.

```
num1 = Model1.objects.all().length()
num2 = Model2.objects.all().length()
num3 = numFromDatabase
FormSet1 = modelformset_factory(Model1, extra=num1, max_num=num1)
FormSet2 = modelformset_factory(Model2, extra=(num1*num2), max_num=(num1*num2))
FormSet2 = modelformset_factory(Model3, extra=(num1*num3), max_num=(num1*num3))
context = RequestContext(request)
if request.method == "POST":
    forms1 = FormSet1(request.POST)
    forms2 = FormSet2(request.POST)
    forms3 = FormSet3(request.POST)
    if forms1.is_valid() and forms2.is_valid() and forms3.is_valid():
        counter = 0
        objects1 = forms1.save(commit=False)
        for object1 in objects1:
            object1.attrib = stuffFromDatabase
            object1.save()
            for i, object4 in enumerate(Model4.objects.all()):
                ***object2 = forms2.__getitem__(counter * num2 + i).save(commit=False)***
                object2.attrib = stuffFromDatabase
                object2.related1 = object1
                object2.related4 = object4
                object2.save()
            for i in range(num3):
                object3 = forms3.__getitem__(counter * num3 + i).save(commit=False)
                object3.attrib = i
                object3.related1 = object1
                object3.save()
            counter += 1
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
else:
        forms1 = FormSet1()
        forms2 = FormSet2()
        forms3 = FormSet3()
    return render_to_response('path/to/page.html', {'forms1': forms1, 'forms2': forms2, 'forms3': forms3}, context_instance=context)
```

I've tried to figure out if I'm passing it bad numbers, but from what I can tell I'm not. I really have no idea what's causing it to stop there, as, on the page, it displays the correct number of forms. (Using the above numbers again, forms1 is 2 forms long, forms2 is 8 forms long, and forms3 is 6 forms long.)

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: Here's the traceback. I also marked the line that breaks, just inside the first inner for loop.

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/path/to/views.py" in hardwaremktg
  263.                  object2 = forms2.__getitem__(counter * num2 + i).save(commit=False)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py" in __getitem__
  61.         return self.forms[index]

Exception Type: IndexError at /my/view/
Exception Value: list index out of range
```

Comment: Which line is causing the error exactly? Can you post the entire traceback?

Comment: I edited the post to add the traceback.

Comment: Please don't explicitly call double-underscore methods like `__getitem__`. Just do `forms2[counter*num2+i]`.

Answer (score 0):

This should be clear when you think about what the values are inside each loop.

Let's assume you have 4 Model4 objects in your database. The first time through the outer loop, it will iterate through the inner loop 4 times. The value of `counter * num2 + i` will be (1 * 4 + i) for i=0->3, ie 4, 5, 6 and 7. Now, at the end of the first time through the outer loop, you increment `counter`, so the calculation is now (2 * 4 + i) - ie 8, 9, 10, 11: oops, you only have 8 forms in `forms2`.

(Note you could have found that yourself by simply inserting a print statement inside the loop.)

It seems like you should think again about some of this logic. Not only is there that bug, but it is also very inefficient: you're doing things like querying Model4 each time through the loop unnecessarily. Plus, see my comment about accessing `__getitem__` explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It didn't directly fix it, but your comments got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out. It turns out the POST data contained duplicate fields, because I didn't put a prefix on the formsets. These are the changed lines:

```
...
forms1 = FormSet1(request.POST, prefix='prefix1')
forms2 = FormSet2(request.POST, prefix='prefix2')
forms3 = FormSet3(request.POST, prefix='prefix3)
...
forms1 = FormSet1(prefix='prefix1')
forms2 = FormSet2(prefix='prefix2')
forms3 = FormSet3(prefix='prefix3')
```